# Key Error when binding minimum_height to boxlayout in scrollview

Tags: python, kivy

How do I bind minimum_height to a BoxLayout in a ScrollView on the python side?

This is where I am at:

```
class BrokenScreen(screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BrokenScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # build widgets
        self.pop = Popup(auto_dismiss=False,size=(.8,.8))
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint_y=None)
        self.scroll = ScrollView()

        # bind height, this is the line bringing about the error
        self.box.bind(minimum_height=self.box.setter('height'))

        # integrate
        self.scroll.add_widget(self.box)
        self.pop.add_widget(self.scroll)
```

When I attempt to compile, I receive the following error:

```
KeyError: 'minimum_height'
```

What do?

Comment: Could it be that there's a missing `)` on that line? Even with the corrected parentheses, does the `bind` method for `box` have an optional argument named `minimum_height`?

Comment: I have adjusted the OP so that all brackets were accounted for; those were an artifact of translating my code into a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BoxLayout` does have an attribute named `minimum_height`.

Which is automatically computed minimum height needed to contain all children.

Therefore, you are not suppose to modify `minimum_height` in `BoxLayout`

To prevent such modification, Kivy has made it as ***read only***.

That is the reason why you have no access to modify it.

Best way to prove it is to open up boxlayout.py inside of your Kivy folder.

```
minimum_height = NumericProperty(0)
'''Automatically computed minimum height needed to contain all children.

.. versionadded:: 1.10.0

:attr:`minimum_height` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.NumericProperty` and
defaults to 0. It is read only.
'''
```

Comment: Thank you for walking me through this--I did read your answer after it was originally posted. Since then, I have referenced the kivy source code multiple times to resolve issues I've had with objects. This seems to be a good first or second step in the debugging process when I am stumped. Here's a link for anyone else who may come across this post: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/kivy/uix

Answer (score 1):

Miket25 asked if `box` has the `minimum_height` argument.

I was able to resolve my problem by using a GridLayout instead. <strike>So, probably not</strike> (EDIT: I was wrong about whether or not `box` has `minimum_height`, see the accepted response).

```
    # build widgets
    self.pop = Popup(auto_dismiss=False,size=(.8,.8))
    self.grid = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y=None) #<- change this
    self.scroll = ScrollView(size=self.size)

    # bind height, this is the line bringing about the error
    self.grid.bind(minimum_height=self.grid.setter('height')) # only changed var name

    # integrate
    self.scroll.add_widget(self.grid) # changed var name
    self.pop.add_widget(self.scroll)
```